# How to escape or terminate an escape sequence in C

Tags: c, escaping

I have sequences of characters I'm feeding to a decoding function:

For example:

```
"\x05three"
```

(Yes, that's a Pascal-style string. The function translates length-prefixed strings to null-terminated strings.)

I wrote a few test cases, among which:

```
"\x04four"
```

And to my surprise, that came out as "Oour". Looking closer, it turns out that the specification on [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for Visual Studio allows that, my sequence is basically interpreted as `\x04f`, which would be 79 in base 10 (thus my resulting string becomes "Oour", 79 being 'O')

My solution was simply to split the string:

```
"\x04" "four"
```

**The question: Is there another way to escape or terminate an escape sequence?**

Comment: `0x04f` is 4*16+15 = 79, so 'O'.

Comment: 0x4f (hex) is 79 in decimal, which is the letter "O".  80 in decimal (not 0x80 which is a hex number) is the letter P.  0x80 is 128 decimal, which is not a standard ascii character

Comment: Thank you both. I'm ashamed now. I wonder if I grabbed the decaf tin this morning...

Comment: There you see the dangers of even having a decaf tin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you cant try `"\004four"` for instance. Actually, even `"\04four"` will probably do, because `f` is not an octal number.

Comment: @AndersK. Probably. And a big DUUHHH! for me!

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Damn, re-duh, that's true, it's supposed to be octal. Maybe it's just Visual Studio messing with me, but it's definitely doing something.

Comment: No, you've used `\x`, and the `x` makes it hexadecimal.

Comment: I remember that when using octal, three numbers following backslash is as far as you can get. But since I've been through learning c literals in time of pdp-11 where we used to use octal, I never bothered to investigate how it behaves with hexadecimal. Because it would make perfect sense if two hexadecimal digits would terminate escape sequence as well. Perhaps, it's also three.

Comment: Ah! With the hex notation, it can be \x00 or \x0000, the later making it Unicode. I guess the compiler stops at the first non-hex character and pads.

Comment: So now you know more than I do. Well, not anymore ;-)

Comment: I don't think that this should be considered as a proper general answer as it will not work if the remaining (unescaped) string starts with a valid octal digit.

Comment: @romor, 1. You don't have to either think this should be considered a proper general answer or consider it t a proper general answer. 2. The answer starts out with using three-digits octal and explains why two may work, so that is covered too.

Comment: How can you escape the desired string `"\x04" "7-zip"` using this approach?

Comment: @romor, `\"\\x04\" \"7-zip\"` — like this? That is, if I understand you right, which I'm not sure of…

Comment: @romor, or more likely, since you want the digit after digit, you meant `"\0047-zip"` (no, it's not 47).

Comment: I meant second and I see now. Octal escaping only takes 3 digits max, even if succeeding characters are in the range 0-7. Hex escaping behaves different and fails when succeeding characters are in the range 0-f.

Comment: @romor, yes, that's right, hex behaves differently, apparently because octals came along earlier and a byte in octal is no longer than three characters, 255 being 377. With hex, you can still do `\x{4}7-zip` and actually the same goes for octal with `\o{4}7-zip`. But it may require a modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You just write strings next to each other:

```
char a[3] = "1\02"   // {'1', '\2', '\0'}  
char a[4] = "1\0""2" // {'1', '\0',  '2', '\0'}

sizeof("1\02") // 3
sizeof("1\0""2") // 4
```

Comment: `You just write strings next to each other` indeed MPelletier does as [stated in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8229521/3789665): `My solution was simply to split the string: "\x04" "four"`.