# null character inside string

Tags: c++, string, null-character

From [Rules for C++ string literals escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/c-string-literals-escape-character) ,Eli's answer

```
std::string ("0\0" "0", 3)  // String concatenation
```

works because this version of the constructor takes a char array; if you try to just pass "0\0" "0" as a const char*, it will treat it as a C string and only copy everything up until the null character.

Does that mean space isn't alloted for entire string , ie the string after \0 is written on unalloted space ?

Moreover the above question is for c++ string, I observed same behaviour for c strings too .
Are c and c++ strings same when I add null char in middle of string during declaration ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here: Why do you need to use strings instead of just character arrays?

Comment: There is a set of strings which could be represented as a array of pointers to char[] , but is represented as char[] with \0 separating strings and int[] to store offsets of strings

Answer (score 2):

The char array is copied into the new object. If you don't specify, how long the char array is, C++ will copy until the first null character. How much additional space is allocated is outside the scope of the specification. Like vectors, strings have a capacity that can exceed the amount required to store the string and allows to append characters without relocating the string.

Comment: so something like  char w[]="qwe\0""0uqwe";
 printf("%s\n%s",w,w+4); is wrong ?

Comment: `char w[]="qwe\0""0uqwe"` casts a `const char*` to `char[]`. That's wrong.

Comment: The string capacity isn't *completely* outside the scope of the spec: you're guaranteed that capacity >= size.

Comment: "How much *additional* space is ...". Better?

Comment: So is size here size of "qwe" or size of "qwe\0""0uqwe" ?

Comment: What does `sizeof("qwe\0""0uqwe")` tell you? What does `strlen("qwe\0""0uqwe")` tell you?

Comment: strlen considers string only till \0 , while sizeof considers entire array

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*` assumes the input is a C string. 
C strings are `'\0'` terminated and thus stops when it reaches the '\0' character.

If you really want to play you need to use the constructor that builds the string from a 
char array (not a C-String).

STL sequence containers exceed the amount required to store automatically

Example :

```
int main () {

string s="Elephant";

s[4] ='\0'; //C++ std::string is NOT '\0' terminated
cout<<s<<endl; //Elep ant

string   x("xy\0ab");   // C-String assumed.

cout<<x; //xy
  return 0;
}
```