# C++: Read files that dont have an extension

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ostream, istream

I have some files with the type "File"
I mean instead of "Resource\sample.txt", their name is "Resource\sample"
Now I want to read them with c++ and store them in a string.
Here is my code:

```
std::stringstream textBuffer;
std::fstream fileHandle;
std::string content
fileHandle.open("Resource\sample", std::ios::in);
textBuffer << fileHandle.rdbuf();
content = textBuffer.str();
fileHandle.close();
```

But when I compile this the value of "content" variable is equal to "".
Help me on this . Thanks in Advance.
Please note that the only problem is that the file has no extension such as .txt or .dat or .bin of whatsoever.

Comment: Filename does not matter, look for an error elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: program works correctly if the file has ".txt" extension

Comment: Check the file stream after you open it: `if (!fileHandle) { std::cerr "Failed to open\n"; return 1; }` - Doesn't solve the problem, but catches it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not properly escape the backslash in your filename string. You need to either escape the string:

```
fileHandle.open("Resource\\sample", std::ios::in);
```

or use a raw string literal:

```
fileHandle.open(R"(Resource\sample)", std::ios::in);
```

Comment: Because if change the address to "Resource\sample.txt" and add the ".txt" extension to the file as well everything works properly.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/c-string-literals-escape-character. A backslash means that the Compiler will not put a backslash into the string but a character that depends on what follows the backslash. A common escape sequence is '\n' for newline. "\s" will be reduced to "s". You can check that in a Debugger or with printf.

Comment: My only Explanation why it succeeds when adding ".txt": you have a program that wrote this file. You did the same error and the file on disc is not "Resource\sample.txt" but "Resourcesample.txt" (and on disc you have "Resource\sample" but no "Resourcesample")!?