# Write a text into file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I just started new project in Visual Studio 2017 and I tried to write some text into file. But after I run my code, no file is created.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream file_program("D:\test2.txt", ios::out);
    if (file_program.is_open())
    {
        file_program << "test";
        cout << "OK";

        file_program.close();
    }

    int age;
    cin >> age;

    return 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `"D:\\test2.txt"` instead of `"D:\test2.txt"` - `\t` in a string has special meaning, so you need to escape the first \

Comment: You can also use forward slash `/`. Works fine on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/rules-for-c-string-literals-escape-character

Comment: So stupid :/ i was trying relative and absolute path, different folders because windows rights, but this didn't cross my mind... Thank you guys!

Comment: Next time, use a debugger and step into functions; you'd see that the argument wasn't showing what you thought it would be showing; and now you likely have some very strangely named files kicking around ... if the open succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you have to escape the backslash.

```
"D:\test2.txt"
```

Here you have `'\t'` which is effectively a tabulator.

```
"D:\\test2.txt"
```

Would be correct.