# Why does type char return a different value?

Tags: c++

If the largest value `char` can hold is 255 then how come if I make a variable of type `char number` and set it equal to `= 255;` then `std::cout << number;` the program returns `\377`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`\377` *is* 255.**

[`\N` gives you the value represented by the *octal* number `N`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220539/560648)

Decimal 255 is octal 377 is binary 1111 1111 is hex FF.

Also be aware that the largest value `char` can hold is only 255 if `char` on your system/compiler is unsigned and 8-bit. A signed `char` will not go up that high, and will overflow if you try to make it. It's possible you want to use an `unsigned char` for certainty (and `assert(CHAR_BIT==8)` if you're really paranoid :P).

Comment: probably `std::oct`

Comment: @Tyker: That would switch numeric output into octal, but it wouldn't simulate C++ escape sequences by prepending a backslash... [and streaming a `char` emits an ASCII character of that value anyway](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/032da6d5680a7b7c). OP is leading us on a bit.

Comment: `std::cout << number << std::endl;` worked. I'm new to c++ so I wouldn't even know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Probably `std::oct` and converting the `number` to `int` or `unsigned`.

Comment: It's conceivable that OP's shell outputs unprintable characters as escaped octals.

Comment: @Peter: [Still no](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9093c7a14b036dff); you'd have to jump through a few hoops to manage that!

Comment: @molbdnilo: Ah, that could be it.

Comment: Re “the largest value `char` can hold is only 255 if `char` on your system/compiler is unsigned and 8-bit”: Well, technically, the largest value `char` can hold is also 255 if `char` is signed and 9-bit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Touché!