# What is the value between a part of txt and another part of txt?(new)

Tags: c, text-files

So ive ask a question early , heres the link : [What is the value between a part of txt and another part of txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568544/what-is-the-value-between-a-part-of-txt-and-another-part-of-txt?answertab=active#tab-top)

So to find out what character or value it is , i wrote a code that will printf "used" if it gets the value, heres the code :

```
char buffer[50];
    FILE *fr = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fgets(buffer, 49, fr);
    printf("test%stest", buffer);
    if(buffer == '\0'){
        fclose(fr);
        fr = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        printf("\nUsed\n");
    }
```

'\0' is just an example, i tried to use all "control character" from here : [Rules for C++ string literals escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/rules-for-c-string-literals-escape-character/10220539#10220539) and the program still didnt print out "used", so im sooooo curious that what value is in the lines just like the question i asked earlier, or maybe i code the program that wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `if(buffer[0] == '\0')`? The variable `buffer` cannot be `'\0'` but one of its elements can. However it is more usual to check the return value from `fgets`.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thx!! You need to use buffer[0] to check the value, after i change to it, it works !! thx alot!