# how to use backslash as delimiter in c and C++?

Tags: c

I have a string `"abc\asd\zxc\12as"`, I want to use `strtok()` to split the string based on `\\` delimiter. But having a `\\` is treated as escape character. How can we handle this situation?

Also how can I get only the 3rd word(eg. `zxc`) from `strtok()`?

Comment: why do you tag with coth C and C++?

Comment: `string s = R"(abc\asd\zxc\12as)";`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/rules-for-c-string-literals-escape-character

Comment: Raw strings as shown by @Eljay or escaping the backslashes "\\"...

Comment: In C, you cannot split a string literal using `strtok` because attempted modification of the storage for the string literal results in *undefined behavior*. However, you can use the string literal as an initializer for an array of `char` and split the string in that array using `strtok`.

Comment: In C++ exactly the same – solely that their type is `char const*` right from the start and you'd need to cast constness away to be able to provoke UB...

Comment: Apart from: Third argument: `char *w; for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; ++i, data = nullptr) { w = strtok(data, "\\"); if(!w) { /* error handling; make sure to abort loop appropriately */ } } /* use w */`

Comment: I highly recommend not using C-Style strings in C++.  Also, the `strtok` cannot be used with a character string literal because `strtok` modifies its parameter string.

Answer (score 3):

Inside string literals in C and C++, you can use the `\` character to refer to other characters that you can't type nicely in code - for example `\n` is understood to be the line feed character.

So for example the c-string `"Hello\nWorld"` if printed to the console would appear as

```
Hello 
World
```

Because of this in general the `\` character needs to be escaped itself. For your example, this means using `\\` in places where you might expect to use `\`.  For example, this string `"Hello\\World\\again"` in the C source file would print as `"Hello\world\again"`

Comment: i tried to fix the escaping but didnt get it right, ironically it isnt easy

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thx - fixed it - was also surpried at how hard it was.

Answer (score 0):

as string, `\a` means escaped `a`, escaping is usefull when you have chars like , newline(\n), tabs
etc

what you need to do is escape de \ i.e. replacing them with \\

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call something like `strtok(string, "\\")`.

To get the third word, you'll have to call `strtok` three times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "abc\\asd\\zxc\\12as";
    char *firstword = strtok(string, "\\");
    char *secondword = strtok(NULL, "\\");
    char *thirdword = strtok(NULL, "\\");
    printf("%s\n", thirdword);
}
```

Also, if you have any control over the data in this situation, you might want to choose a different delimiter character, since `\` is going to be eternally inconvenient.  Could you use `|` instead?