# Why am I getting error code in c++ before C

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {

cout<<"Welcome to "C++"";
cout<<"Welcome to \"C++\"";
    return 0;
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: A) you should show the error message. Regardless, you have nested double-quotes in your string, which is not valid.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `"Welcome to "C++""`, the quotes confuse the compiler. It sees `"Welcome to "`, which is the string part, and then it sees `C++` (not as part of the string) which confuses it.

Instead, do this:

```c
cout << "Welcome to \"C++\"";
```

That escapes the double-quote characters. You escape a character by putting a `\` before it (a backslash, typically above the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on your keyboard). This means to do something special. In this case, it just means "don't end the string, treat the double-quote as part of it". But it can have other meanings depending on what you are escaping. For example, `\n` makes a newline. I explain a bit more in the next paragraph.

Warning: don't go putting a `\` (backslash a.k.a. whack) before every character in your string. Depending on what character you put the `\` before, it may do something different. For example, just doing `\"` makes a double-quotation-mark. Doing `\n` makes a newline. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220539/16886597) for a list of them.

---

Side note: although it isn't required in C/C++, I suggest (consistently) indenting your code for readability

Comment: Another option is to use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) instead, then you don't have to escape characters, eg: `cout << R"(Welcome to "C++")";` Everything between the `()` is treated as-is as the string's content.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not familiar with that (I almost only use C, not C++), but if you posted that as an answer, I'd upvote it though :)