# How to start file format name with a digit in ofn.lpstrFilter ? It doesn't allow to write 3 at the start?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape or terminate an escape sequence in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229521/how-to-escape-or-terminate-an-escape-sequence-in-c)

`ofn.lpstrFilter` is not allowing me to write the digit "3" at the start of an extension? Which filter do I need to use?

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = "text1 (*.txt)\0*.txt\03D text (*.txt)\0*.txt\0";
```

In above example, just after `\0`, I am using `3D`, but lpstrFilter does not allow me. Why? I don't want to use space in between them.

Output should be like:

```
text1 (*.txt)
3D text (*.txt)
```

If I use space between `\0` and `3D` then output is:

```
text1 (*.txt)
 3D text (*.txt)  // note one space is added before 3D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are accidentally using an [octal character constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx). When you write `\03D...` you expect the compiler to interpret this as `\0` `3D...`. However, the compiler follows the rules and turns this into `\03` `D...`. Since this does not produce a `NUL` character the `*.txt` extension preceeding it extends to the next `\0` character. The following `*.txt` extension is now misinterpreted as the display string which will happily show up in the file type dropdown list.

The solution is to split the string and write the following instead:

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = "text1 (*.txt)\0*.txt\0" "3D text (*.txt)\0*.txt\0";
```

This will properly terminate the `\0` and prevent the following numeric character from being interpreted as part of this escape sequence.

As an aside, since this is WinAPI code you should probably use `TCHAR`s instead of `char`s. The line of code would then look like this:

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = _T( "text1 (*.txt)\0*.txt\0" ) _T( "3D text (*.txt)\0*.txt\0" );
```

Comment: Just for readibility and consistency, I might even take it a step further and separate each filter item individually, eg: `_T("text1 (*.txt)\0" "*.txt\0" "3D text (*.txt)\0" "*.txt\0")`. You do not need to wrap each one with its own `_T()` since the compiler merges multiple string literals together, so you can pass the final merged literal to a single `_T()`.

Comment: @Remy You cannot wrap them into a single `_T()`. Once the preprocessor is done (assuming a Unicode build) you'll wind up with `L"first" "second"` and the compiler will complain about incompatible strings.

Comment: +1 Far better idea is to forget you ever heard of `TCHAR` and use the native platform character type, `wchar_t`. Unless of course you are still targeting Windows 98.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick but the native **platform** character type is `WCHAR`. Whether that is an alias for `wchar_t`, `unsigned short`, or something else altogether depends on the version of the platform SDK you are using and the specific target platform you are building for. By far the best idea is to learn about character encodings and move on.

Comment: I tested it with the Embarcadero's C++ compiler, it DOES allow multiple literals to be wrapped in a single `_T()` exactly as I showed, and the output is correct. So the preprocessor is merging the literals together first, then passing the result to `_T()`.

Comment: @Remy As per the C++ standard macro invocations are replaced during phase 4, string concatenation is performed during phase 6. As such my statement holds true, you cannot wrap multiple string literals into a single `_T()` preprocessor macro.

Comment: it is also very common (and in fact MS does this routinely in their code) to use a marker-char in a single string, that you then swap with a zero-temrinator before you perform your invoke. This is very common in strings held in string tables for localization. Ex. `"text1 (*.txt)|*.txt|3D text (*.txt)|*.txt|"`. Before using it walk the string and change all `'|'` characters to zero-terminators. Just make damn sure it **ends** with whatever marker char you're using to ensure the double-terminator required by the API.